# Annoying white gaps between fluid images in FF

Tags: firefox, fluid-layout

I have a 4-column fluid layout with no gutters. 
Within the columns there are images that scale up and down depending on the window size.

http://moargh.de/daten/kni/index-images.html

The scaling works more or less fine on Mac OS X in all browsers* but Firefox (v26). Firefox renders ugly white or semi-transparent gaps between the images both horizontally and vertically.

(* Only Safari renders a white gap on the right side of the screen of the window size is not divisible by 4.)

Does anybody know how to avoid that?

Comment: The page looks fine for me on Firefox 28... have you already fixed it?

Comment: No, I didn’t solve the problem yet … What’s the newest FF version? I only have v26 and it tells me it’s the newest.

Comment: Try it in [Aurora](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/channel/#aurora) and let us know if it works

Comment: Doesn’t work in Aurora either …